# Calculate resistance for high amperage LEDs for control with Arduino

Tags: arduino, led, mosfet, resistors, resistance

I'm trying to control my LED strip with my Arduino, so I decided to buy a FET. Now I want to learn why and what kind of resistance should be put between the gate and the Arduino.

I have a long (1560 cm) LED strip connected (in parallel). The strip consumes 1.2A per meter, so it needs 18.7A.

I bought a N-Channel Mosfet (IRF540N, which can handle up to 30A), but the problem is that I'm new on resistances.

I know the formula of Ohm's Law, but my problem is that I don't understand it well.

What resistance should I put?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and poorly written... FETs have gates, not bases. They are turned on by voltage, not current. IRF540 may not fully turn on with 5V given by Arduino output. Maybe get a logic level FET?

Comment: Hi Wesley, first, sorry for my poorly written, english is not my first language.. what model of transistor/mosfet should i buy? i know that fet turn on V, but i saw many videos and all put a resistence (1k) bettwen the mosfets gate and the arduino, so i wanna learn why

Comment: Hey Casy, English is not my first language either but anyway.. The gate of the FET has some parasitic capacitance. To avoid "inrush current" or a potential "short" from the point of view of a microcontroller, some resistance is added (100R is common, 1k is a but high IMO). In some cases the gate resistor will also diminish ringing/oscillation.

Comment: This FET is ok for 20A (absolute max 33A. Always stay well below max for safety). The resistor between arduino and the gate protects and the gate and the arduino. It will work without but at your own risk. The resistor between the gate and the ground (see my answer) is more important. Without it the FET may turn on and off unpredictably.

Comment: That FET may work, but it's going to be marginal with only around 5 volts on the gate.  The FETs that work best with low gate voltage are newer devices generally available only in surface mount packages.  Adafruit does carry the leaded-package irlb8721pbf for Arduino projects, and that may work a little better at 5v gate drive.  One thing you can do that would help would be to separate your strings and use one FET to control each string, from a common power supply.  Or even use multiple FETs in parallel to share the job of powering your parallel connected strings.

Comment: "Oh no, I used my "English is not my first language" card, and it is not very effective."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must connect the negative side of the LED strip to the Drain (D), the ground (the negative side of the power supply) to the Source (S) (without any resistor)
and the Arduino output to the Gate (G). Apply at least 4V to the Gate but no more than 18V. So your 5V from Arduino is fine. On the gate you need two resistors: Between the Arduino output and the Gate, put a resistor of 140 Ohms (or between 100 and 1K if you don't have 140 Ohms exactly). Between the Gate and the ground, put a resistor between 200K and 800K (any value in between is ok). HTH.

Comment: Can you explain me why you pick that resistances?

Comment: The high value pull-down is to maintain the FET off during "unknown" states, such as the Arduino booting, etc. I typically use 10k~100k. The gate resistor depends a lot on what you are driving the FET with. But lets say an Arduino can drive 40mA at 5V. So 5V/40mA= 125R would be fine. Thats conservative since you are only pulling 40mA extremely briefly (even if you repeat that with PWM).

Comment: According to the datasheet which I recommand reading, the gate draws 250µA. Even with a 10K resistor you will still have enough current, but we use between 100R and 1K not to impede the current too much. More than 1K may be unreliable. the resistor to the ground reduce the voltage in combination with the other resistor, that's why it's better not to put less than 200K to keep voltage reduction minimal, but 10K~100K as Wesley uses, may be fine but reduces voltage by a fraction.

Comment: It doesn't reduce voltage if you put in the right place. 250uA is the leakage, not the current it draws to fill the Gate capacitor. Too much gate resistance will give you poorer rise times (and therefore slower turn on times and longer times on not fully-on states, so higher power dissipation).

Comment: You'r right. I was reading it too quickely. It's wierd: They don't write the gate current...

Comment: @Fredled - the don't specify the gate current because it depends on the derivative of gate voltage, and the capacitance which they do specify.

Comment: I understand. I always thought that gate leakage was what is effectively used by the gate. So gate current is defined by some arithmetic with the voltage, capacitance + leakage? Anyway it remains in the order of a few µA, right?

Comment: No for the second question. When turning on a FET, it is essentially briefly a short circuit and can get all the way up to the Amp range (very high dV/dT and high gate capacitances). Look into gate driver ICs and their applications.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fra467.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use low value for **R4** like 100 Ohmes. **R1** is used as pull down resistor typically use around 100k for consistency of transistor when unknown states of arduino and preventing switching the transistor.Using higher value help reduce the unwanted current draw through R1. FETs are based on voltage not on current. They just draw number of \$\mu A\$ while continuously active. Actually it will run without problem even if there is no **R4**. But it may help for safety in case of higher current is drawn.But higher **R4** reduce the sensitivity of gate. See the data sheet whether voltage between Gate and Source is enough to flow current through Drain and Source.See charastric of MOSFETs.

Comment: You're going to have to explain R2.  Current sense resistor?  Model of wiring losses??

Comment: @ChrisStratton Nope. Here I used it is as a current controller for LEDs. The question's intention is about Gate. I just put it for completeness.